# how to get value from json response object

Tags: jquery, json

i want to get amount value from following json response how to get

```js
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"amount":1231,"firstName":"dfsdf","lastName":"lasernmae","email":"vijaitest@gmail.com"}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

```js
 complete: function(response) 
     {
      
      
      var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(response);
      console.debug(jsonObject.responseText.amount);
    

     }
```

for above coding i am getting  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO1](https://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/y4wwcac5/)**

```
var data = '{"readyState": 4, "responseText": {"amount":1231,"firstName":"dfsdf","lastName":"lasernmae","email":"vijaitest@gmail.com"}, "status": 200, "statusText": "OK"}';
var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data);
console.debug(jsonObject.responseText.amount);
```

if you have responseText as String you can use following code:

[**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/jtgspddu/2/)

```
var resT = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
console.debug(resT.amount);
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/jtgspddu/1/ check this. if you are getting response same as this, there should not be a problem.

Comment: but here i am getting double quotes before curly braces for responseText.

Comment: @vijaikarthik : check updated answer. you will get your solution

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your object has the variable name of data.  Just do..

```
var amount = data.responseText.amount;
```

If you are getting that response from a server, and still need to parse it.

```
var data = JSON.parse(theObjectsVariableNameHere);
var amount = data.responseText.amount;
```

Comment: getting error VM8211:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o